# Tooth Chart Toggle Buttons for Multi-Page Form?

Tags: javascript, image, toggle

Howdy folks and thanks in advance for taking the time to check out this post. I've searched high and low for a tutorial to help me solve this particular problem to no avail. I'm hoping somewhere here might be kind enough to offer me some guidance?

Basically my client would like a multipage form wherein users are able to select individual teeth from a dental chart as illustrated in the images I've linked to below. The first image shows a dental chart without any teeth selected and the second image shows the same chart with random teeth selected:

[Dental Chart w/out Selections](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-5H6Pi01ANv0/TjJJFOkHRJI/AAAAAAAAAE0/NJJU9xfWDmo/s144/Screen%252520shot%2525202011-07-28%252520at%25252010.28.21%252520PM.png)

[Dental Chart w/Selections](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-GXJe2_pVK34/TjJJGMx5I9I/AAAAAAAAAE4/ZTv1jIrxgaY/s144/Screen%252520shot%2525202011-07-28%252520at%25252010.29.01%252520PM.png)

Once a user has selected individual teeth the corresponding data needs to appear within a multi-page form submission summary that my client receives via email in the following manner:

"Tooth Chart Implants : 3, 8, 9, 16, 19, 27, 31" for each of the teeth selected. Users should also be able to reset their selections via a "Reset" button if they wish to start over.

Just wanted to know what you guys might suggest as the best way to go about achieving this? My client's site is a Joomla! site just so you know what I'm working with. :)

Thanks again for any and all help!

Best,

Shane

Answer (score 0):

well. This is gonna be a *itch, or so I feel.
Nothing comes to mind except of cutting each individual tooth out like a separate **.png**, and then absolutely positioning each tooth image inside of div in a way that recreates your example with a tooth number being an image alt attribute for example.

You'll also will have to create pink version for all these cutted out images.

After this you can bind click event that would add "active" class to that individual image on click and also change src attribute so user would see selected tooth.

**jQuery example**

```
$('.tooth').click(
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('active').attr('src','whiteVersion.png');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active').attr('src','pinkVersion.png');
    }

)
```

After that you can loop through these individual images and generate that string: 3, 8, 9, 16, 19, 27, 31

**again - jQuery example**

```
var selected = '';
$('.tooth').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        if(selected === ''){
            selected = $(this).attr('alt');
        } else{
            selected += ', ' + $(this).attr('alt');
        }
    }
})
```

****Easier way:****
would be to have large tooths image that has numbers in it for each tooth. Then user can type them numbers in himself.

Comment: also - check ot javascript canvas.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to respond, this is great! :)